# How to manage array saved in reactjs state

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

this is my first post there :)

So How to manage array saved in reactjs state?

Context: a web site I react with, which provides multiple-choice questions to students and is managed by the teacher, an academic case

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "textvalue": "Les licornes existent-elles ?",
  "singlecorrectanswer": true,
  "explication": "hyhy-bèikb_b",
  "answer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "author": 1,
      "textanswer": "Evidemment, oui",
      "correct": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "author": 1,
      "textanswer": "Bien sur que non",
      "correct": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I have this as an attribute of an Input for the question `value: this.state.question.text value`
But I can't modify the field by entering text, maybe because onChange is not defined.

In addition, I want the user to be able to modify each answer.
For the answer it is the same problem :
I will realize a map on my "answers", a solution is to create an onChange function that will deal with the index of the map and the array of the state and modify it. But this solution is a bit ugly. Do you have a better solution to automatically bind the "value" of the field to the state?

My apologies for my English, I'm french

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the view rendering code for the question. The JSON object is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have provided code we could review.

Yes, your issue is likely caused because you did not provide an onChange event.
This is in the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

I tested this here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-ives-ccy4u

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's not the best. As jasdhfiu said I had to provide a onChange event

Here is my code

```
handleQuestionChange = (field, value) => {
    let question = Object.assign({}, this.state.question);
    question[field] = value;
    this.setState({question}, () => this.updateError());
};

handleQuestionThemeChange = (value) => {
    let question = Object.assign({}, this.state.question);
    question.theme = this.state.themes.find(o => o.label === value);
    this.setState({question}, () => this.updateError());
};

handleAnswerChange = (field, value, index) => {
    let question = Object.assign({}, this.state.question);
    question.answer[index][field] = value;
    this.setState({question}, () => this.updateError());
};
```

And my event which are place on buttons :

```
onChange: (e) => this.handleQuestionChange('textvalue', e.target.value)
onChange: (e) => this.handleQuestionChange('explication', e.target.value)
onClick={() => this.handleAnswerChange('correct', !answer.correct, index)
onChange: e => this.handleAnswerChange('textanswer', e.target.value, index)
onChange={e => this.handleQuestionThemeChange(e.target.value)}
```

If there is a simpler way let me know 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use onBlur instead of onChange so that you don't need to update state on every character change.
To use onBlur you need to use defaultValue instead of value.

```
  <input defaultValue={this.state.question.text value} onBlur={e => updateValue(e.target.value) /* your update function */} type='text' />
```